# How to use a C# variable in script? if var is bool and it is having true value div is enable

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

In View Rager Engine code:

```
        @{
            bool btn248=false;
                    if (chk1.checked==true)
                    {
                        btn248= true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This in Html code:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
        <div data-btn248="@btn248" id="tabsUL">
if btn248 is true then im visible otherwise partially visible.
</div>
```

This is Scripting file

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                debugger
                if (document.getElementById("tabsUL").dataset.btn248 == "True") {
                    document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.pointerEvents = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.opacity = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.pointerEvents = "none";
                    document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.opacity = 0.6;
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you using Razor to build your HTML? What does your current DOM HTML provide? What does this code currently do?

Answer (score -1):

You can store that variable in your view's script using below code.

```
    <script>
  var btnValue='@btn248';
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        debugger
                        if (document.getElementById("tabsUL").dataset.btn248 == "True") {
                            document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.pointerEvents = "visible";
                            document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.opacity = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.pointerEvents = "none";
                            document.getElementById("tabsUL").style.opacity = 0.6;
                        }
                    });
                </script>
```